# Which is Better NOSQL Solution for Time Series Log Data

Tags: hbase, time-series, schema, nosql

I need some advice for selecting NOSQL solution and how to design a schema for my data.
Now I'm considering Hbase but if you think that is not a good choice, please give me  advice.

I have about 10TB(a bit less) of log data in text.
The Format is something like this.

`| key1 | key2 | timestamp | column1 | column2 | column3 | column 4 |`

There are my requirements below.

1. I need to fetch data by {key1, key2} and the result will be an array of {timestamp, column1} or an array of {timestamp, columnN}. each array size will not be over a thousand.
2. Need to fetch data with date range filter.
3. Unique count of key1 might be over than a billion. that's why the data size so big.
4. column1 and column2 are hardly accessed together.
5. Result array size will be getting grow as time goes so I need to clean up some old data.
   (column value will not be modified but will be removed when the data expired.)

Now I consider a schema looks like this.

`rowkey - | key1, key2 |
column family - column1_type, column2_type , ..... , columnN_type
column - key :timestamp, value: columnN_value`

I don't have experience on Hbase. A piece of advice will be very helpful
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An existing solution called [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/overview.html) is available that handles time series data. OpenTSDB is scalable, distributed time series database. It uses HBase to store and retrieve time-series data.